# BadRequestObjectResult does not return detailed error message to the client

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have a Azure function with an HTTP trigger. It produces a 400 response when an input value is not specified:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(artistName))
{
    return new BadRequestObjectResult("Artist name not specified.");
}
```

When the function is running locally (`func host start`) and the API is called incorrectly (I am using `curl -X POST ...`), the above error message is shown.

When deployed to Azure and called in a similar way - instead of the detailed error message - only `Bad Request` is returned.

Why?
How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue for function runtime `2.0.11888` that HttpTrigger does not return response content properly.

If you want to solve this, go to Application settings, pin your `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to previous runtime `2.0.11857-alpha` until new version is released.

See [Azure Functions Runtime 2.0.11888 Preview](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/117).

**Update**

This issue has already been fixed from [2.0.11933](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.11933-alpha).